# How do I install the Aether II Minecraft mod on Mac?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-aether

I asked this question on Minecraftforum.net and got no response.

I'm trying to install the Aether II mod for Minecraft on my Mac. I've watched a number of YouTube videos on how, but they all reference my /bin directory. Ever since the 1.6 update, I no longer have a /bin directory, only /versions.

Can anyone provide step-by-step directions (not a video) for installing this mod on Mac OSX? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the Aether mod has been updated for 1.6?

Comment: @fbueckert It's not, but the new launcher comes with 1.5.1 already installed. I'm working up an answer that handles that wrinkle.

Answer (score 2):

The numbered jar files in your `versions/*` folders work exactly like the old `bin/minecraft.jar` file used to. Now there are just multiple copies of `minecraft.jar` all renamed to keep them separate.

If you're using a 3rd-party launcher, you can copy the `1.5.1.jar` file in your `versions/` folders to wherever your launcher keeps its version of Minecraft. Rename the copy of `1.5.1.jar` to `minecraft.jar` and proceed from there. If this is your situation, this is where my instructions end because I don't know your launcher's setup.

However, you can also use the new Minecraft launcher directly, leveraging its new multi-version features. This is what I'm doing now, since I find it more robust than messing with other launchers. Here's a step-by-step guide to get you to the point where the mod's install instructions will make sense again:

1. Make a copy of your `versions/1.5.1` folder and put it beside the 1.5.1 folder. Rename the new folder, the jar file, *and* the JSON file all to `aether2` + `.jar` and `.json` extensions as appropriate (OS X may not show you the extension of the files, in which case don't worry, they'll be unchanged and stay correct). You should now have a `versions/aether2/` folder containing `aether2.jar` and `aether2.json`.

   (The name "aether2" is not important – it could be anything, so long as you use the exact same name in every place where `aether2` appears in these instructions. Stick with `aether2` until you grok the process.)
2. Then open the JSON file with a text editor (**not** Notepad, since it mangles config files; use Wordpad, or get Notepad++). Change the line inside that reads

   ```
   "id": "1.5.1",
   ```

   to say `aether2` (or whatever you named the files and folder)

   ```
   "id": "aether2",
   ```

   and save the JSON file.

   Now you will have a nice fresh new Minecraft jar version that you can start modding. This is why the new Minecraft launcher is awesome – it supports multiple versions, including multiple modded versions.

   (Yes, you have to use the 1.5.1 version as a starting base. Aether II isn't updated to 1.6.2 yet.)
3. Now that you've got that, you need a new folder to keep your world saves and mods separate from the vanilla Minecraft files. Create a folder anywhere (I like to keep it in my `.minecraft` folder though) named whatever you like, but for convenience I suggest (you guessed it) `aether2`. This folder name doesn't have to match the names under `versions/`, but it's convenient for it to match.
4. Finally, you need to create a new launcher profile that will use the new version and new folder. Start the Minecraft launcher and create a new profile, then click **Edit Profile**. Change *Profile Name* to something nice like "Aether II". Click the checkbox beside *Game Directory* and change the end of the path to point at your new world folder, so something like

   ```
   /Users/YourOSXUserName/Library/Application Support/minecraft/aether2
   ```

   (or the equivalent on the other operating systems). Now, and this is the all-important part, pick `aether2` from the *Use version* dropdown list. Double-check that your Minecraft login is correct (especially if you share this computer with other Minecraft players), then click **Save Profile**.

   You should now have a nice new login profile that runs a copy of Minecraft that's entirely separate from the vanilla Minecraft release!

You are now ready to install the mod, but first, check that everything is working and log in with the new profile. Create a world, quit, and look in your new `.minecraft/aether2/saves/` folder to make sure your worlds with this profile are saving to this folder instead of the main `.minecraft/saves/` folder.

Now mod away! When the mod instructions tell you to do something to `bin/minecraft.jar`, just do that to `versions/aether2/aether2.jar` instead and it will work the same. When an instruction tells you to put a file in your `.minecraft/mods/` or `coremods/` folders, put them in `.minecraft/aether2/mods` and `minecraft/aether2/coremods/` folders instead.

And watch for that tricky dot in `.minecraft`. All modding instructions (including most of my own here) will tell you about your `.minecraft` folder, but on OSX it's missing the dot. This is normal and not a problem, unless you let it confuse you. This is just an odd difference that Minecraft has on Mac OS X that you have to get used to.

Comment: Thank you for your extremely detailed answer. I tried what you said, but keep getting stuck when it gets to the actual modding. I was hoping for directions on the modding part as well. Every video has their own different way of installing this mod, and there's always some point where what is on the video's screen and what's on my screen are different. I'm about ready to give up on this mod. It looks awesome, but it's been an incredible headache to install.